# How to emulate "ON CONFLICT" PostgreSQL statement using JPQL

Tags: postgresql, jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I need to convert PostgreSQL native queries to JPQL. How the following two SQL statements can be translated:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (id, some_data) VALUES (?1,?2) ON CONFLICT (id) DO NOTHING;
INSERT INTO other_table (id, other_data) VALUES (?1, ?2) ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET other_data = ?2
```

PostgreSQL ensures that each of the two statements will be executed atomically and will never fail due to conflict. How to archive the same functionality with JPA (EclipseLink)?

Comment: There is no way you can do that with an obfuscation layer like JPA

Comment: The last statement is what the JPA merge method is meant for - insert or update the row if it exists, it just won't do this in a single statement.  Otherwise, you are better off using native SQL, especially after the first statement.

Comment: @Chris are you sure merge will work correctly in case of two concurrent threads? I suspect they both will try to perform INSERT and one of them will fail.

Comment: Define works correctly. Statements are generally wrapped in transactions and so not visible anyway until the transaction completes. If there is an overlap, one fails and would need to be retried.

Comment: @Chris "ON CONFLICT" is atomic and guaranteed not to throw errors, so I would like to get the same functionality. It seems however that it is unique to PostgreSQL. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT